# Issues with trying to initialise a project and push to GitHub that was a previous repo I had deleted

Tags: git, github, repository

Using the GitInit command I wanted to create a new repository on GitHub.
I had deleted the previous repo thinking I could start afresh.

Repsone from terminal1: `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/jonasnoori/code/jnoori31/JavascriptWesbos/.git/`

After git add . && git commit - m: `On branch main Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.`

After git push origin master: `error: src refspec master does not match any error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jnoori31/Javascript30Days.git'`

As a newbie to code confused as to what is happening and how to resolve it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+On+branch+main+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 1):

Try `git push origin main` instead of the `git push origin master`